# How to overlay time series from each day on one plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bokeh

I am trying to plot data from a data frame with hourly frequency on a plot where each day is its own line and the x-axis is hour. The data frame is shown below and so is the resulting graph I get when simply setting the x-axis as 'hb' and y-axis as 'BaseCase'. The plot is close to what I want, but connects the end points to the starting point. How do I go about avoiding the straight lines across the plot?

```
scens = pd.read_csv(---)
scens['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(scens['datetime'])
scens.drop(scens.tail(2).index,inplace=True)
source = ColumnDataSource(scens)
p = figure()
p.line(x='hb', y='BaseCase', source=source)
show(p)
```

The above code is how I get the plot at the bottom of the post

[image: Dataframe]

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: how exactly did you get these plots? Sometimes I get these kind of lines when the data is not ordered but here it looks like it connects the first and last points.

Comment: Always provide a [mre] with code, **data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

If you are opened to other packages, consider seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns 
sns.lineplot(data=df,x='hb', y='BasedCase', 
             hue= df['datetime'].df.normalize())
```

Or with just pandas:

```
for date, d in df.groupby(df['datetime'].df.normalize()):
     d.plot(x='hb', y='BasedCase', label=date)
```